# libuv simple send udp

Tags: c, udp, libuv

I'm doing a multiplatform shared library in C, which sends UDP messages using libuv, however I don't know much about libuv and I don't know if my implementation is good, or if there is another solution besides libuv.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uv.h>

#define IP "0.0.0.0"
#define PORT 8090
#define STR_BUFFER 256

void on_send(uv_udp_send_t *req, int status) {
    if (status) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Send error %s\n", uv_strerror(status));
        return;
    }
}

int send_udp(char *msg){
    uv_loop_t *loop = malloc(sizeof(uv_loop_t));
    uv_loop_init(loop);
    
    uv_udp_t send_socket;
    uv_udp_init(loop, &send_socket);
    
    struct sockaddr_in send_addr;
    uv_ip4_addr(IP, PORT, &send_addr);
    
    uv_udp_bind(&send_socket, (const struct sockaddr*)&send_addr, 0);

    char buff[STR_BUFFER];
    memset(buff,0,STR_BUFFER);
    strcpy(buff,msg);

    uv_buf_t buffer = uv_buf_init(buff,STR_BUFFER);
    
    uv_udp_send_t send_req;
    uv_udp_send(&send_req, &send_socket, &buffer, 1, (const struct sockaddr*)&send_addr, on_send);
    
    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_ONCE);
    
    uv_loop_close(loop);
    free(loop);
    
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    send_udp("test 123\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation has multiple issues to date:

1. I'm not sure a single loop iteration is enough to send an UDP message on every platform. This is something you can check easily with the value returned by `uv_run`, see the [documentation](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/loop.html#c.uv_run) for `uv_run` when using the `UV_RUN_ONCE` mode:

> `UV_RUN_ONCE`: Poll for i/o once. Note that this function blocks if there are no pending callbacks. Returns zero when done (no active handles or requests left), **or non-zero if more callbacks are expected** (meaning you should run the event loop again sometime in the future).

If you would keep your code as-is, I would suggest to do at least this:

```c
int done;
do {
    done = uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_ONCE);
} while (done != 0);
```

But keep on reading, you can do even better ! :)

2. It's quite costly in terms of performance, `uv_loop`s are supposed to be long lasting, not to be created for each message sent.
3. Incomplete error handling: `uv_udp_bind`, `uv_udp_send`, ... they can fail !

### How to improve

I would suggest you to change your code for one of the two following solutions:

- Your library is used in a libuv context (a.k.a, you don't try to hide the libuv implementation detail but require all people who wish to use your library to use libuv explicitly.
  You could then change your function signature to something like `int send_udp(uv_loop_t *loop, char *msg)` and let the library users manage the event loop and run it.
- Your library uses libuv as an implementation detail: you don't want to bother your library users with libuv, therefore its your reponsibility to provide robust and performant code. This is how I would do it:

  - `mylib_init`: starts a thread and run an `uv_loop` on it
  - `send_udp`: push the message on a queue (beware of thread-safety), notify your loop it has a message to send (you can use `uv_async` for this), then you can send the message with approximately the same code you are already using.
  - `mylib_shutdown`: stop the loop and the thread (again, you can use an `uv_async` to call `uv_stop` from the right thread)

It would look like this (I don't have a compiler to test, but you'll have most of the work done):

```c
static uv_thread_t thread; // our network thread
static uv_loop_t loop; // the loop running on the thread
static uv_async_t notify_send; // to notify the thread it has messages to send
static uv_async_t notify_shutdown; // to notify the thread it must shutdown
static queue_t buffer_queue; // a queue of messages to send
static uv_mutex_t buffer_queue_mutex; // to sync access to the queue from the various threads

static void thread_entry(void *arg);
static void on_send_messages(uv_async_t *handle);
static void on_shutdown(uv_async_t *handle);

int mylib_init() {
    // will call thread_entry on a new thread, our network thread
    return uv_thread_create(&thread, thread_entry, NULL);
}

int send_udp(char *msg) {
    uv_mutex_lock(&buffer_queue_mutex);

    queue_enqueue(&buffer_queue, strdup(msg)); // don't forget to free() after sending the message
    uv_async_send(&notify_send);

    uv_mutex_unlock(&buffer_queue_mutex);
}

int mylib_shutdown() {
    // will call on_shutdown on the loop thread
    uv_async_send(&notify_shutdown);

    // wait for the thread to stop
    return uv_thread_join(&thread);
}

static void thread_entry(void *arg) {
    uv_loop_init(&loop);
    uv_mutex_init_recursive(&buffer_queue_mutex);
    uv_async_init(&loop, &notify_send, on_send_messages);
    uv_async_init(&loop, &notify_shutdown, on_shutdown);

    uv_run(&loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT); // this code will not return until uv_stop is called

    uv_mutex_destroy(&buffer_queue_mutex);
    uv_loop_close(&loop);
}

static void on_send_messages(uv_async_t *handle) {
    uv_mutex_lock(&buffer_queue_mutex);

    char *msg = NULL;
    // for each member of the queue ...
    while (queue_dequeue(&buffer_queue, &msg) == 0) {
        // create a uv_udp_t, send the message
    }

    uv_mutex_unlock(&buffer_queue_mutex);
}

static void on_shutdown(uv_async_t *handle) {
    uv_stop(&loop);
}
```

It's up to you to develop or find a queue implementation ;)

### Usage

```c
int main() {
    mylib_init();

    send_udp("my super message");
    
    mylib_shutdown();
}
```